# How to get the value from the parent x-data in a nested setup?

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

Currently trying figure out how to make use of Alpine to simplify the management of a list. most of it is fine, but can't seem to get the value for show and showAll to make it to the items on the list.

```
<div x-data="{ show:false, showAll:false }">
    @foreach($items as $item) <!-- laravel blade bit -->
        <div x-data="{ active:{{ $item->foo }} }" x-show="show && (active || (!active && showAll))">
            <div>stuff</div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <button @click="show = ! show">btn1</button>
    <button @click="showAll = ! showAll">btn2</button>
</div>
```

So basically the active variable is fine, despite there being a lot of them, but show and showAll from the parent don't seem to count.
To note, the x-datas aren't direct parent child as shown here, there's stuff in between. And secondly I haven't been able to check if it's okay to have a conditional in x-show, might just have made a mistake there.

Comment: The buttons have missing the closing `</button>` tag. Otherwise the code is fine. Do you see the correct values in Alpine.js Dev Tools extension?

Comment: The tag was just a mistake making the example here, changed. 
Downloaded the extension and the only thing it sees is a piece in the navigation. The component on the page itself isn't being picked up. Even the areas which are currently working.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example here that reproduces the problem? (Without blade template parts.) 1-2 child component is enough.